# Getting Spinner changes in listView

Tags: android, listview, spinner

I have a `ListView` with a `CustomAdapter` that has up to 50 rows( only 11 on the screen at once). Each row contains a `spinner` and two `EditText`s. I pass 3 sets of data to the adapter for each of the three columns. When a `spinner` item is selected or text changed I want to amend the relevant data set inside the adapter so that it can be retrieved by the calling `activity`.

I can get a `OnItemSelectedListener()` registered against each `spinner`, however, I can't find a way to know which row the `spinner` was on. Because of that I can't update the data set.

This is the adapter.

```
SQLiteDatabase      db;
Activity            mActivity;
int             []  mCategories;
String          []  mComments;
String          []  allCategories;
int             []  mAmounts;
String          []  spinnerValues;


TransCatListAdapter(Activity activity, int[] categories, String[] comments, int[] amounts){
    super (activity, R.layout.transcat_row, comments);

    mActivity   = activity;
    mCategories = categories;
    mComments   = comments;
    mAmounts    = amounts;

    db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(activity);

}
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    if (row==null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.transcat_row, null);
    }
    Spinner     SPNCategory = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.trncatrow_category);
    EditText    ETComment   = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.trncatrow_comment);
    EditText    ETAmount    = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.trncatrow_amount);

    SPNCategory.setAdapter(new CategorySpinnerAdapter(mActivity, R.layout.categoryspinnerstyle, DatabaseMethods.getCategories(db)));

    ETComment.setText(mComments[pos]);
    ETAmount.setText(Utils.formatAsMoneyString(mAmounts[pos]));
    return (row);
}
```

Comment: Was your question resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you want to be able to register an `OnItemSelectedListener` to your spinners but you want to be able to identify WHICH spinner it was right? Try this

```
getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
...
    spinner     SPNCategory = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.trncatrow_category);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new YourSpinnerListener(pos);
...

private class YourSpinnerListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    private int mSpinnerPosition;

    public YourSpinnerListener(int spinnerPosition) {
        mSpinnerPosition = spinnerPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

This class that implements the OnItemSelectedListener now has a reference to the position of the spinner.

Have fun!

Comment: Brilliant, that was **EXACTLY** what I was trying to do. Perfect reply. Thank you very much.